# while loop - done < command instead of done < file

Tags: bash

For moving all files in sub folders into the current folder I use this script

```
while read f
do
    mv "$f" .
done < file_list
```

this works great but i have to generate the `file_list` with

```
find . -name *.avi > file_list
```

what i want is to add the command directly to my while loop

```
while read f
do
    mv "$f" .
done < find . -name *.avi
```

but bash tells me  `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.' ``

What is an easy solution to pipe the find command into my while loop?

Comment: Hi there! This is the wrong, error-prone (see what you happen if you have files with leading spaces or newline characters) and inefficient approach. You should use `-exec` option of `find` to have a sound way of doing what you want. Are you open to that?

Comment: *\*.avi* will expand to multiple file names and passing as arguments to *find* (which will interpet as options) glob must be escaped or quoted (see answer)

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: And [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas interesting read thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

proper way to do this is pipe

```
find . -name '*.avi' |
while read f
do
    mv "$f" .
done
```

the result from first command "`find . -name *.avi`" will feed the second.

This is call a pipe (from the symbol `|` ).
You can think of pipe as a temporary file like

```
find . -name '*.avi' > file1.tmp
while read f
do
    mv "$f" .
done < file1.tmp
rm file1.tmp
```

---

As pointed out filename with space or newline are likely to cause error.

If the only purpose is to move file, use @Terdon's commands.

Also you must quote `*.avi` or it will break on second run.

```
find: paths must precede expression: `foo.avi' 
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-name'?
```

Comment: Well, _proper_ way would be to use `-print0`, and `while IFS= read -r -d ''; do...` Without these, the loop will fail on file names with newlines.

Comment: I always forgot about newline files, given that list was generate with `find` at first place it would have error before and piping would not change that.

Comment: True. But if you're calling it the _proper_ way, it's better to be on the safe side :)

Comment: I will accept this answer as it is the specific answer my question. For future readers please check out [@terdon answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592515/294056) as it is the proper way to do it:). Thx for all the insights!

Comment: @terdon `-print0` is a non-standard solution for a problem that did no longer exist when print0 has been introduced, since there is `find -exec +` since 1988.

Comment: @schily `-print0` is perfectly standard for GNU find which is what most of our users who might be asking a question this basic would be using, but if you have a better way of making piping `find` results to a shell loop safe, please post an answer, I would be very interested in seeing it!

Comment: @terdon `-print0` is badly planned as it would require dozens and dozens of commands to be changed to support it. We recently discussed in a POSIX teleconference and decided it is not worth adding it. Most shells do not support it with `read` `awk` does not support it ... BTW: Another clean method would to enhance the currently experimental`-call` feature from the bultin `find` command in `bosh`.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need any loop here, `find` can do it for you:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -exec mv {} . \;
```

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze `-iname` will match *'\*.AVI'* and *'\*.avi'*

Comment: and `*.Avi`, and `*.aVI`... and possibly `*.avı`, `*.AVİ` in some locales

Comment: My version of `find` requires that `{}` is the last argument of `-exec` command. `-exec mv -t . {}` should work. It is also ok to use `+` (many arguments at once) instead of `\;` (one command per file).

Comment: @aragaer what `find` is that? What operating system? And yes, the `+` can also work, sure.

Comment: It appears on my current computer exec works fine with `{}` in the middle and `;` in the end and only complains about `{}` when using `+`. Probably that was some older version of find.

Comment: @aragaer I think you were probably thinking of `+` since that is the one that complains. I have never seen find (albeit I am only familiar with GNU find, so maybe some non-GNU ones acted differently) complain if the `{}` isn't last with `\;`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use process substitution.

```
while IFS= read -r f
do
    mv -- "$f" .
done < <(find . -name '*.avi' )
```

In shells like `bash`, compared to the pipe approach, it has the advantage of *not* running the loop in a subshell, so the variable assignments you would do in the loop for instance are not lost afterwards. In `bash` (or `zsh`), you'd rather do:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -rd '' f 
do
    mv -- "$f" .
done 3< <(find . -name '*.avi' -print0)
```

using NUL delimiters to be able to work with arbitrary file names, using fd 3 instead of 0 as `mv` may prompt the user and would read the answer on stdin which would be the output of `find` if you used 0.

Or using the `find` command itself

```
find . -name '*.avi' -exec mv -t . {} +
```

Using `+` means we pass many arguments at a time to `mv` which saves having to run one `mv` invocation per file. `-t` is a GNU extension. With other `mv` implementations, you can change it to:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -exec sh -c 'exec mv "$@" .' sh {} +
```

Answer (score -4):

A halfway position between the two existing answers is to "inline" the find and use a **for** loop.

```
for f in `find . -name '*.avi' `
do
    mv "$f" .
done
```

The back-ticks are what make the find command execute in place and then its output is substituted.

**Downside** is spaces and unexpected weird characters in filenames can cause issues.   The answer by @Terdon is superior.

Comment: This is [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). If you didn't say the method is flawed, I would vote down. I guess it makes some sense to have this answer here as a *warning*.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski exactly - showing why something is sub-optimal is just as important as showing the best answers.